# PDO utf8_encoding my text string twice in INSERT?

Tags: php, unicode, pdo

Relevent code:

```
$status = $db->run(
    "INSERT INTO user_wall (accountID, fromID, text, datetime) VALUES (:toID, :fromID, :text, '" . time() . "')",
    array(":toID" => $toID, ":fromID" => %accountID, ":text" => $text)
);
```

I am taking input text from javascript, throwing it in an AJAX call to handle it, which calls a function which includes these lines of code.

The text string in question is: "`Türkçe Türkçe Türkçe!`"

Upon investigating the database, the following value is saved "`TÃƒÂ¼rkÃƒÂ§e TÃƒÂ¼rkÃƒÂ§e TÃƒÂ¼rkÃƒÂ§e!`", which is double utf8_encode'd.

When viewing the text by SELECTing it from the database, I get "`TÃ¼rkÃ§e TÃ¼rkÃ§e TÃ¼rkÃ§e!`", which is how they *should* be saved in the database in the first place.

As far as I know, I am not encoding the data as it is being prepared by PDO...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encoding is a b*tch. You need to make sure it is as you expect it to be in several places:

1. The HTML page with the Javascript. Set it to utf-8 with a meta tag like:
   `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`
2. The connection to your database. Execute the query `set names 'utf8'` after connecting to the database (and before any other queries).
3. Your database field. In MySQL it's called a *collation* set it to `utf8_general_ci` (ci stands for case-insensitive).

If you have these 3 your data should always be, and stay, utf-8 (unless you're doing encoding yourself).

For good measure, make sure your source code files are utf-8 as well. Windows typically defaults to iso.

Comment: Duly noted. I was doing 2 of 4, 3 if gedit saved in unicode, which it actually might. I was always unsure of what utf8_general_ci was vs. utf8_bin or some of the other variations...

Comment: `utf8_bin` makes your data explicitly binary. I don't know the percs but it might make it so you can't do text searches anymore or something like that. I never use any binary collations. Perhaps someone else can enlighten you on that.

Comment: I only recently discovered this myself: utf8_general_bin makes searching sensitive to accent marks (so é is different from e), but utf8_general_ci makes it insensitive.

Comment: I see. I did know about `ut8_general_cs`; which makes your fields case sensitive.